# Como instanciar um objeto dessa classe no C#

Tags: c#, winforms, orientação-a-objetos

Estou lendo a apostila da Caelum sobre C# e orientação a objeto, aí coloquei em **Conta.cs** o seguinte código:

```
namespace Banco
{
    class Conta
    {
        public int numero;
        public string nome;
        public double saldo;

        public bool Sacar(double valor)
        {
            if (this.saldo >= valor)
            {
                this.saldo -= valor;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Tem a classe **Conta** com o método **Sacar**.
Diz que para instanciar um objeto tem que fazer o seguinte:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Conta r = new Conta();
    r.numero = 1;
    r.nome = "Flano";
    r.saldo = 300;

    if (r.Sacar(250.0)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Operação realizada com sucesso!");
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Saldo insuficiente!");
    }
}
```

Eu entendo como funciona tudo, só não sei onde colocar esse "button".

Comment: Seu objeto do tipo `Conta` já está instanciado, poderia ser mais claro na sua dúvida ? porque pelo que entendi, você tem esse código de botão e não sabe onde colocar correto ?

Comment: Não se preocupe com a classe `Conta` para isto. Ela é apenas seu modelo, ela não tem relação com a apresentação que você está tentando fazer. Claro, que você usa ela na apresentação mas ela em si não faz parte da apresentação. Você copiou isto no projeto ou mandou o VS gerar o código do Form para você e só adicionou este trecho? A apostila mostra todo o código ou só deu esse trecho? Está me parecendo que falta você criar todo o Form (o VS gera o código para você) e depois encaixar esta parte.

Comment: Eu sei que a classe é a referência para eu instanciar os objetos. Deve ser isso mesmo, deve está faltando criar o formulário. Mas lá estava assim, não mostrava como criar o form.

Comment: Isso @EnzoTiezzi eu instanciei, mas não sei onde colocar.

Comment: primeiro você precisa identificar se seu projeto, é um `Windows Form`, caso seja você precisará colocar um botão na sua tela, clicar sobre esse botão 2 vezes e incluir esse código que está no método `button1_Click` no código que ele gerar automaticamente, que será semelhante a esse que você tem.

Comment: O Button será colocado na Interface Gráfica. https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-MRRwz5qyaE8/Tn0EKfJ8E9I/AAAAAAAABAY/16jDCAKW4cs/DynamicButtonsInWinforms.gif

Comment: O visual Studio tem um atalho de teclado para indentar o código automaticamente: `CTRL + k + d` ;)

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, identifiquei aqui tudo. Valeu mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1-) Abra o Visual Studio;

2-) Crie um projeto Windows;

3-) Você deve ver agora o desenho de um formulário. Se não vê, fuce aí até encontrar;

4-) Deve haver uma aba a esquerda com diversos controles. Expanda a aba, encontre um controle `Button` e o arraste para o formulário. Pode deixar na posição que quiser;

5-) Dê um duplo clique nesse botão que você colocou no formulário!

<strike>6-) ???</strike>

7-) Lucro!

6-) Isso vai abrir o arquivo de código do formulário, já com um método de clique do botão pronto para você preencher. Por baixo dos panos, o Visual Studio também já associou o evento de clique do botão a esse método.

Ponha seu código que trata a conta dentro desse método gerado pelo Visual Studio. Daí é só rodar a aplicação e ver como funciona, depurar e tudo o mais.

Essa metodologia toda também funciona com um projeto *web*. Mas projetos *web* são um pouco mais complexos, por isso recomendo focar em aplicações Windows e aplicações de console até dominar os conceitos que estás a aprender por enquanto.

É importante mais a frente entender também como a associação do evento de clique é feita ao método. Então fuce bastante, ok? Uma das principais características de bons programadores é a curiosidade. Boa sorte!

Comment: O último parágrafo é o mais importante.

Comment: Consegui rapidinho. Estou consciente que é uma pergunta básica, mas é que estou vindo da web. A faculdade tá cobrando aí tomei vergonha na cara para estudar. Obrigado, deu certo!

Comment: Valeu, vou olhar tudo.